# Запуск программ с нужным языком. Линукс

Tags: linux, консоль, locale, fedora, execute

Для запуска Gimp с английским языком я использую в консоли

```
LC_ALL=C gimp
```

Но попытка создать кнопку запуска на панели XFCE4 не сработала.
Запуск программы через неё выводит сообщение "нет такого файла"

Можно, конечно, сделать скрипт для запуска, но нет ли другого способа?

Comment: Пихайте скрипт прямо в кнопку например, `bash -c "LC_ALL=C exec gimp"`

Comment: >>Но попытка создать кнопку запуска на панели XFCE4 не сработала.<< — что именно писал в desktop-файл? вероятно проблемы с escape'ами

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо сработало. Я как раз думал попробовать таким способом.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, так и писал LC_ALL=C gimp и так писал, "LC_ALL=C gimp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае, когда какая-либо программа запускается не через оболочку, а непосредственно другой через системный вызов `exec*`, то чтобы установить некоторые переменные перед запуском оной можно воспользоваться утилитой [`env`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=env).

В данном случае запись в *.desktop файле будет выглядеть как:

```
Exec=env LC_ALL=C gimp %U
```

Последнее `%U` — желательное дополнение, чтобы с помощью этой записи можно было открывать различные файлы.

Аналогичную команду, конечно же, можно задать через гуёвые утилиты...

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.